# Unable to Unmarshal XML response using JAXB classes

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

Exception :

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.cleartrip.com/hotel/hotel-search-response", local:"hotel-search-response"). Expected elements are (none)

---

MyTestFile.txt(XML) :

```
<hotel-search-response xmlns="http://www.cleartrip.com/hotel/hotel-search-response" xmlns:hotel-info="http://www.cleartrip.com/places/hotel-info" xmlns:common="http://www.cleartrip.com/hotel/common">
<search-criteria>
    <booking-date>2018-12-12+05:30</booking-date>
    <check-in-date>2018-12-14+05:30</check-in-date>
    <check-out-date>2018-12-16+05:30</check-out-date>
    <number-of-rooms>1</number-of-rooms>
    <number-of-nights>2</number-of-nights>
    <number-of-room-nights>2</number-of-room-nights>
    <city>Bangalore</city>
    <country>IN</country>
</search-criteria>
<currency>INR</currency>
```

---

JAXB Class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "hotel-search-response", propOrder = {
"searchCriteria",
"additionalCurrency",
"currency",
"baseUrl",
"hotels",
"pgfeeJson",
"pgchargeJson"
})
public class HotelSearchResponse {

@XmlElement(name = "search-criteria", required = false)
protected SearchCriteria searchCriteria;
@XmlElement(name = "additional-currency",required= false)
protected AdditionalCurrency additionalCurrency;
@XmlElement(required = false)
protected String currency;
@XmlElement(name = "base-url", required = false)
protected String baseUrl;
@XmlElement(required = false)
protected Hotels hotels;
@XmlElement(name = "pgfee-json", required = false)
protected String pgfeeJson;
@XmlElement(name = "pgcharge-json", required = false)
protected String pgchargeJson;
}
```

---

Java main class:

```
JAXBContext jc= JAXBContext.newInstance(HotelSearchResponse.class);
        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller ums = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        HotelSearchResponse emp=(HotelSearchResponse) ums.unmarshal(new    File("E:/MyTestFile.txt"));
```

Comment: Hi now it is giving following ecveption:

Comment: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property searchCriteria is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
 this problem is related to the following location:
  at protected org.tg.service.jaxb.hoteladditionalinfo.classes.SearchCriteria org.tg.service.jaxb.hoteladditionalinfo.classes.HotelSearchResponse.searchCriteria

Comment: SearchCriteria is child class of HotelSearchResponse. Is it necessary to mention "namespace" in child class also ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the have a `@XmlRootElement`. Second, you need to specify the namespace (since you use namespaces).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "hotel-search-response", namespace = "http://www.cleartrip.com/hotel/hotel-search-response")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "hotel-search-response", propOrder = { "currency", "baseUrl",
"pgfeeJson", "pgchargeJson" }, namespace = "http://www.cleartrip.com/hotel/hotel-search-response")
public class HotelSearchResponse
```

Above, the `propOrder` is simplified.

Comment: No, actually XML is huge i have posted only 10-20n lines, still xml is there

Comment: Hi now it is giving following ecveption: – abhinandan abhinandan 18 hours ago  
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions Property searchCriteria is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder this problem is related to the following location: at protected org.tg.service.jaxb.hoteladditionalinfo.classes.SearchCriteria org.tg.service.jaxb.hoteladditionalinfo.classes.HotelSearchResponse.searchCriteria – abhinandan abhinandan

Comment: SearchCriteria is child class of HotelSearchResponse. Is it necessary to mention "namespace" in child class also ?

Comment: @abhinandanabhinandan `propOrder` has to contain **all** the fields in the desired order. In my example, `propOrder` is simplified. Did you read all my answer?